# Connecting Salesforce with ERP system

Tags: salesforce, synchronization, middleware, erp

my boss gave me the task to connect (bidirectional) an erp system with the salesforce system of our customer. I have to finish the task 'til Xmas (2014!). LOL

### ERP > Salesforce

In the erp system we can implement some hooks (they will be invoked on create/update/delete events) to give sync events to the middleware of the erp system. These sync events will be processed and can fire against the Salesforce SOAP-Inferface, but: The middleware is stateless - no login information(salesforce-session-Ids) can be shared over multiple sync events.

**So I think, we should login and logout at every sync event. Is it right, or is there an easier solution?**

### Salesforce > ERP

If someone will change the data in salesforce, how we can sync back the changed data?
What techniques offers salesforce to do that in near-realtime? To prevent answers like "RTFM": Of course, I downloaded the salesforce developer guide, but 1700pages are to much to finish the project 'til end of the year.

**I'd appreciate if someone could give me a hint, how a "hook" can be implemented in salesforce.**

Answer (score 0):

**ERP > Salesforce**

Yes, unless you build some sort of middle layer to store and send transactions in bulk. 
I would suggest some sort of batching to avoid running out of API calls.

**Salesforce > ERP**

Most reliable solution for this is using [Outbound Messaging](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_setting_up.htm). You'll need some sort of infrastructure in place to receive the messages of course.

In my personal experience Outbound Messaging fell short, and I used [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Streaming_API) Push Topics and a custom queue to handle my synchronization needs-- but due to your short timeline I would use Outbound Messaging.

Good Luck!